# Convert string to DateTime in a specified TimeZone (not local nor UTC)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I have `DateTime` represented as string (e.g. "2023-08-13T11:32:59")
But the time zone of this `DateTime` is not UTC nor the local time zone

I want to parse this string and then convert it to the local time zone.

What I did so far is convert it to UTC and then convert to local time zone.
I wrote this code that does the job but looks cumbersome, is there a better way?

```
DateTime sourceDateTime = DateTime.Parse(date);
TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");

DateTime unspecified = DateTime.SpecifyKind(sourceDateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
DateTime utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(unspecified, sourceTimeZone);

DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Comment: Let me just see if I understand: you have this string representation of a datetime specified in a specific time zone (Central European Standard Time), and you want to extract from that your local datetime value? is that correct?

Comment: Do you know juts the name of the TZ or the actual offset? Do you need to take Daylight Savings into account, if so how?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes exactly

Comment: @Charlieface yes the TZ is given, in the example above it's "Central European Standard Time". what I did was first convert is to UTC and then to my local TZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Your `sourceDateTime` *already* has `Unspecified` kind after parsing, so there's no need to specify that again.
- You don't need to go through UTC - you can convert directly from source time zone to target time zone using the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` method.

Thus, the simplified version would be:

```
DateTime sourceDateTime = DateTime.Parse("2023-08-13T11:32:59");
TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");

DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(sourceDateTime, sourceTimeZone, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Be sure you also understand how `ConvertTime` deals with ambiguous and invalid `DateTime` values that can occur near DST transitions.  From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime#system-timezoneinfo-converttime(system-datetime-system-timezoneinfo-system-timezoneinfo)):

> If the value of the `dateTime` parameter is an ambiguous time in the source time zone, it is interpreted as a standard time. If the `dateTime` parameter is an invalid time in the source time zone, this method throws an `ArgumentException`.

If that's not the behavior you desire, then additional logic may need to be implemented.

Comment: I knew I was missing some built in method. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The `TimeZoneInfo` class have a static method for converting `DateTime` values from one time zone to another - called [`ConvertTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=net-7.0#system-timezoneinfo-converttime(system-datetime-system-timezoneinfo-system-timezoneinfo)) - All you have to do is get two instances of the `TimeZoneInfo` class, one for the source and one for the target, and use that method:

```
var datetimeString = "2023-08-13T11:32:59";
var sourceTimeZoneId = "Central European Standard Time"; // UTC + 1
var targetTimeZoneId = "Israel Standard Time"; // UTC + 2 

var sourceDatetime = DateTime.Parse(datetimeString);
// sourceDateTime.Kind property is already Unspecified, no need to change that

var sourceTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(sourceTimeZoneId);
var targetTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(targetTimeZoneId);

var targetDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(sourceDatetime, sourceTimeZone, targetTimeZone);

// targetDateTime is 2023-13-08T12:32:59, kind is still unspecified.
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>SharpLab.IO</kbd>](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
            string strDate = "2023-08-13T11:32:59";
            DateTime utcTime = DateTime.Parse(strDate, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
            System.TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");

            DateTime date = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcTime, sourceTimeZone);
```

Comment: Here you assume the given date is UTC, but I asked about a given date in a third time zone. not UTC or Local

Comment: Then you need two timezones like Zohar solution.